# htmlentities and html_entity_decode do not behave as reverse

Tags: php, decode, html-entities, truncate, htmlspecialchars

I would like to truncate a string to a certain amount of characters. This string contains html characters. Note that I stripped all html-tags from the string. Now, if there is a special character at the breakpoint, it should not break in the middle of the html character, but rather after or before. These example do not work:

```
//example 1
$str = "French for French is fran&ccedil;ais";
$str = substr($str, 0, 27);
//$str contains "French for French is fran&c";

//example 2
$str = "the en dash looks like &#8211;";
$str = substr($str, 0, 25);
//$str contains "the en dash looks like &#";
```

So I thought I should first convert the special characters to single characters, do the truncation and then revert the single characters to special characters. It seems to work in the first example, but not the second.

```
//example 1
$str = "French for French is fran&ccedil;ais";
$str = html_entity_decode($str);
$str = substr($str, 0, 27);
$str = htmlentities($str);
//$str contains "French for French is frança";

//example 2
$str = "the en dash looks like &#8211;";
$str = html_entity_decode($str);
$str = substr($str, 0, 25);
$str = htmlentities($str);
//$str contains "the en dash looks like &#";
```

What should I change to have both examples behave the way I would expect them to?

Comment: look up `mb_substr` as a possible alternative

Comment: Thanks, but if I replace substr by mb_substr in the first two examples, I get the exact same results. Do you have a working example of succesfully using mb_substr with the above example?

Comment: you need to combine it with `html_entity_decode` because even though it is converted to a single character, the special character is style a multi-byte character and substr will carve it up, as you've found.

Comment: I tried my solution it does not work, the characters are badly encoded when using UTF-8.

Comment: `&#8211;` appears not to be a valid unicode character.

Comment: The en dash is mentioned here as one of the html special characters: http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm. Where can I find a correct list of html special characters that are valid unnicode characters? Or what else should I do to get the examples working?

Comment: Your link to ascii characters does state at the top of the page: "[for use with] ISO 10646, ISO 8879, ISO 8859-1" character sets. So this will work with these sets but not UTF-8 or some other default sets. Read up on HTMLentities and define the character set with that, to get the desired result.

Comment: your source code is "ISO-8859-15" encoded, but I'm having the same issue as you in converting it to a html ready string of the specified length. :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

htmlentities uses your `default_charset` php.ini value for its encoding by default.  If you aren't using a charset that supports the entities you're converting, it may not behave as expected.  Try this and see if you get different results.

`htmlentities($str, null, 'utf-8');`

`html_entity_decode($str, null, 'utf-8');`

`mb_substr($str, 0, 25, 'utf-8');`

http://php.net/htmlentities

http://php.net/html_entity_decode

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php

Comment: I do get different results. When I replace "htmlentities($str);" by "htmlentities($str, null, 'uttf-8');" in the third and fourth example above, the first string apears to be empty, the second still outputs "the en dash looks like &#".

Comment: also add the encoding to html_entity_decode and mb_substr

Comment: Glad it worked.  If you don't want to have to do that for every call, again you can update default_charset in your php.ini, or do an ini_set() to set it to utf-8 across the board.

Comment: I had to add the ENT_QUOTES flag to the htmlentities function because apostrophs/single quotes where not converted properly. It now look s like this: $str = html_entity_decode($str, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML401, 'utf-8');